# FindFit and Integration errors

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, polynomials

First off, appologies for what may sound like a newbie question, as I am very new to using *Mathematica*.

I am trying to find a way to get *Mathematica* to give me an expression that would describe the data I get from my code, but I'm not sure how. I've played around with `FindFit` and can't seem to get it to work. Also, I have an integral whose integrand relies on two variables, but I'd only like to integrate with respect to one and keep the other constant. I can do this at the "defining a function" stage but am unsure as to how to display the information thereafter. Any help would be much appreciated! Here is my code

```
a := 3.24077*10^-20 (* km \[Rule] Mpc *)
b := 3.16888*10^-14 (* s \[Rule] MYear *)
c := a/b*(2.99792*10^5) (*Mpc/ MYear*)
H0 := a/b*71 (*1/MYear*)
G := a^3/b^2*6.67398*10^-20 (*Mpc^3/(Kg*MYear^2)*)
\[CapitalOmega]M := 0.27
\[CapitalOmega]\[Gamma] := 8.24*10^-4
\[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda] := 0.73
f := 1*10^-4
y := 100
\[Lambda] := (1/(a^2)) 1*(10^-58)(*1/Mpc^2*)
H[z_] := H0 Sqrt[\[CapitalOmega]M (1 + 
      z)^3 + \[CapitalOmega]\[Gamma] (1 + 
      z)^4 + \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda]]
\[Rho]crit := 3/(8 \[Pi]*G)*(H0)^2 
\[Rho]Pert[r_] := \[CapitalOmega]M*\[Rho]crit*(1 + f*Exp[-(r/y)^2])
M1[r_] := 4 \[Pi] Integrate[\[Rho]Pert[r]*r^2, r]
E1[r_] := 
 1/2*((H[999]*r)/(c*(1000)))^2 - ((G*M1[r]*(1000))/(
   c^2*(r))) - (\[Lambda]*r^2)/(3 (1000)^2)
ScaleFactor = 
  NDSolveValue[
   SetPrecision[{(Sqrt[R[r, t]] (D[R[r, t], t])) == Sqrt[
      2*G*M1[r] + 2*c^2*E1[r]*R[r, t] + (2 c^2 \[Lambda]*R[r, t]^3)/
       3], R[r, 0] == r/1000}, 200], R, {r, 1, 20000}, {t, 1, 15000}];
Plot3D[Re[ScaleFactor[r, t]], {r, 1, 20000}, {t, 1, 15000}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Comoving Radius (Mpc)", "Time (MegaYears)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black]]
FindFit[ScaleFactor[r, 
  t], \[Alpha]*r^n + \[Beta]*t^m, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], n, m}, {r, t}]
ParticleHorizon[r_, t_] := 
 c*Integrate[Sqrt[1 + 2*E1[r]]/D[ScaleFactor[r, t], r], t]
```

Comment: As currently posted, this strikes me as a "can you debug my code" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
sample = Join @@ 
  Table[{r, t, ScaleFactor[r, t]}, {r, 1, 20000, 200}, {t, 1, 15000,  150}];

FindFit[sample, α*r^n + β*t^m, {α, β, n, m}, {r, t}]
```

> ```
> {α -> 0.00118915, β -> 0.00206976, n -> 1.93354, m -> 1.93373}
> ```

?

Comment: Thanks alot, that works great for the FindFit! However, I still get an error when I try to do a ParallelTable for ParticleHorizon, which is defined as follows: `ParticleHorizondata = 
 ParallelTable[
  ParticleHorizon[r, t], {r, 1, 10}, {t, 1, 10}]`

Comment: @kglr Why `FindFit` as opposed to `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: @Q.P., took  the statement  _"I've played around with FindFit and can't seem to get it to work"_  in OP as "how do I get `FindFit` to work".